# C++ Prepend DateTime to console output

Tags: c++, stdout, prepend

Searched around and couldn't find any info on this besides redirecting to files so hopefully someone can help me out.

I have a console application that launches and hooks another process, by default the new process output displays in the first console application.
What I would like to do is prepend a datetime value to all the output, the problem is that I don't control the output from the child process (3rd party app) so the easy solution of adding a datetime to all printed values is unavailable. Is it possible to prepend a string to all `stdout`?

Comment: You put a C++ label on the question: do you want an `stdout` (C) solution, or one which uses `std::cout`?  (The former is impossible, at least portably; the latter is fairly simple.)

Answer (score 0):

Since you confirmed C++ (which implies a solution for
`std::cout` is what is needed, and not for `stdout`): the
obvious solution is a filtering streambuf:

```
class TimeStampStreambuf : public std::streambuf
{
    std::streambuf* myDest;
    std::ostream* myOwner;
    bool myIsAtStartOfLine;
protected:
    int overflow( int ch )
    {
        //  To allow truly empty lines, otherwise drop the
        //  first condition...
        if ( ch != '\n' && myIsAtStartOfLine ) {
            std::string tmp = now();
                //  function now() should return the timestamp as a string
            myDest->sputn( tmp.data(), tmp.size() );
        }
        myIsAtStartOfLine = ch == '\n';
        ch = myDest->sputc( ch );
        return ch;
    }

public:
    TimeStampStreambuf( std::streambuf* dest )
        : myDest( dest )
        , myOwner( nullptr )
        , myIsAtStartOfLine( false )
    {
    }
    TimeStampStreambuf( std::ostream& owner )
        : myDest( dest.rdbuf() )
        , myOwner( &owner )
        , myIsAtStartOfLine( false )
    {
        myOwner->rdbuf( this );
    }
    ~TimeStampStreambuf()
    {
        if ( myOwner != nullptr ) {
            myOwner->rdbuf( myDest );
        }
    }
};
```

And to install it:

```
//  scoped:
TimeStampStreambuf anyName( std::cout );
//  Time stamping will be turned off when variable goes out
//  of scope.

//  unscoped:
std::streambuf* savedStreambuf = std::cout.rdbuf();
TimeStampStreambuf name( savedStreambuf );
//  In this case, you have to restore the original streambuf
//  yourself before calling exit.
```

As far as I know, the articles explaining this (from *C++
Reports*, Sept. 1998) are not on line.

EDIT:

I've actually found them:
http://gabisoft.free.fr/articles-en.html.  I can't believe that
the link still works; it's been years since I had an account
with Free.

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting dest is undefined under "TimeStampStreambuf( std::ostream& owner )", changed it to owner.rdbuf() but can't seem to get any prepended times.

Comment: The first is an obvious typo---I'll fix it.  For the rest, you'll have to post a question with exactly what you're doing.  I've used this technique in many applications, and never had any problems with it (but it's possible that there are other typos---I didn't have the actual sources on the machine I was answering from, and rewrote the code from memory).  You might also check out the articles, particularly the first, which give a more complete implementation, and explain in detail what is going on.